# When a complex matrix is similar to a real matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have a matrix whose entries are in $\mathbb{C}$.

How easy or hard is it to tell in general if a matrix $M$ is similar to a real matrix?

Rasmus pointed out in the comments that in general a matrix has no similar real counterpart. What about for simple matrices like diagonal ones?

Comment: It's not true in general: for $1\times 1$-matrices, similar matrices are equal. Hence $(i)$ cannot be similar to a real matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A complex matrix is similar to a real matrix iff its Jordan canonical form has the property that the Jordan blocks for non-real eigenvalues can be paired up, so that a block for eigenvalue $\lambda$ corresponds to a block of the same size for eigenvalue $\overline{\lambda}$.

Comment: What do you mean paired up? Like they are the same size?

Comment: I mean, they can be partitioned into disjoint pairs.  In each pair you have two blocks of the same size and for complex conjugate eigenvectors.

Comment: Supposing I had the Jordan form of a complex matrix in question, and the blocks were partitioned as you say. What is the way to turn it into a real matrix?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Hi, do you happen to have a proof of this claim? I couldn't find it anywhere.